# Как передать в ответ с сервера целую директорию

Tags: node.js

Знаю как передать обычный файл при запросе на сервер например .html, но можно ли передать целую директорию сразу, а не по одному файлу? Задался этим вопросом потому что когда поднимаешь клиентскую часть с фреймворком vue(npm init vue)и серверную на одном порту то сервер не отвечает на запросы.Серверная часть написана на node.js

Comment: ну, тут одно из двух. либо путь к каталогу. это обычный url, либо содержимое каталога. по одному файлу, да. ну, конечно, можно и в архив каталог поместить на лету. тогда будет один файл.

Comment: Запустите сервер на другом порту, в чем проблема?

Comment: SwaD, при деплое проблем не возникнет? Ведь один URL адрес и у клиентской и у серверной части будет.

Comment: Причем тут деплой, не очень понимаю? Когда вы запускаете клиента npm... у вас стартует develop server(скорее всего 3000 порт). А сервер вы запускаете отдельно командой node . Для отладки самое оно, только в коде клиента подшаманить с портами немного, если вы get/post запросы делаете. А перед сборкой вернуть настройки

Comment: Что вы используете в приложении? чистый js либо фреймверки? например https://github.com/fastify/fastify-static и вообще у вас 2 сервера должно быть) 1 для статики вью, а второй сервер) например поднимаете nginx с ссылкой на статику вью + параметр /api/* пробрасывать на порт 100500...

Comment: Извините, не очень хорошо Вас понимаю, то есть перед загрузкой сайта на VPS можно вернуть все порты к одному значению всё будет нормально работать? Что касается порта клиента, он выставляется автоматически библиотекой vite всегда 5173

Comment: Jour, то есть грубо говоря нужно 2 сервера с разными URL адресами что бы всё работало как надо?